# How to use とりあえず in sentences

Tags: words

I am struggling to understand the word "とりあえず". It seems to mean 'as it stands'.
Here is an example sentence as I understand it:

> とりあえず計画がありません
>   'as it stands we have no plans'

Is this correct? Also, I'm sure I've heard it with the imperative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [goo](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/160965/m0u/%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8A/) ([English](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/55213/m0u/%E5%8F%96%E3%82%8A%E6%95%A2%E3%81%88%E3%81%9A/)), とりあえず means:

1. (Before doing any other things,) First of all

   > とりあえず母に合格を知らせる。 
   >   Let's first tell mother that (I/we/you..) passed.
2. (Without time (or chance) to do anything else, ) for the time being

   > とりあえずけが人に応急処置をした。
   >   We gave first aid to the injured (as an emergency (a temporary) measure)

In this sense I feel that the example given by the OP is not appropriate. But we can say

> とりあえず計画を立てましょう。 
>   Let's first make a plan.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to 'as it stands', it means 'in the mean while' with an implication that it is temporal and with expectations of some other events to follow.

> とりあえず、そこを掃除しておけ。
> 'In the mean while (before I give you further instructions), clean that place.'
>
> とりあえず、ビールを飲む。
> 'I will drink beer for now before doing anything else.'

Comment: While that's true, the example sentence doesn't really work. See fefe's answer for how to fix it.